# 3 points lying on same semicircle

Tags: probability

I'm trying to find answer to the problem of probability that 3 randomly chosen points lies in the same semicircle

Suppose points $A$ and $B$ are placed first. The measure $\theta$ of the minor arc that has $A$ and $B$ as endpoints is uniformly distributed over the interval $(0,\pi)$. For a given $\theta$ probability that point $C$ will be placed so that all three points are on the same side of a diameter is equal to $\frac{2\pi-\theta}{2\pi}$. Integrating(summing) this probability over the interval $(0,\pi)$ gives
$$
\int_0^\pi (1-\frac{\theta}{2\pi})d\theta=\left[\theta-\frac{1}{4\pi}\theta^2\right]_0^\pi=\frac{3\pi}{4}
$$

But the answer should be $\frac{3}{4}$, why I'm getting an extra $\pi$ factor and probability greater than 1?

Can someone help?
Thanks!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @BrianTung Oh I'm extremely sorry. Added

Comment: The uniform distribution over $(0,\pi)$ is not $d\theta$ but $\frac1\pi d\theta.$

Comment: If you want the expected value of $g(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is uniformly distributed over $(0,\pi)$, then you need to evaluate $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} g(\theta) d\theta$.

Comment: I'm little confused, what does my answer $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$ actually represent?

Comment: Is it the case that I have summed up all the probabilities but haven't multiplied their chance of occurrence?

Comment: It represents the answer scaled by $\pi$. You are implicitly using a probability distribution on the angle $(0, \pi)$ that is scaled by $\pi$. For example, your integral implies that the probability of choosing an angle between $0$ and $\pi/2$ is $\pi/2$, instead of $1/2$.

Comment: Thank you all, it's clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that requires no integration:

First pick three random diameters. Then for each diameter, randomly pick one of the end points.

For example,  call the diameters $A, B$ and $C$, and assume we start by randomly picking one end of diameter $A$. Then when choosing end points of $B$ and $C$, three of the four combinations have the points lying on a semicircle. (The only combination that doesn't work is to choose the endpoints of $B$ and $C$ that are NOT adjacent to the chosen end of $A$.)